# Testing (and proving) the randomness of numbers

Tags: random-generation, proof, randomness

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Testing random variate generation algorithms](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30/testing-random-variate-generation-algorithms)

What's a good way to test a series of numbers to see if they're random (or at least psuedo-random)? Is there a good statistical measure of randomness that can be used to determine how random a set is?

More importantly, how can one *prove* a method of generating numbers is psuedo-random?

Comment: Or this one http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30/