# How can I test the fairness of a d20?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, uniform-distribution, dice

How can I test the fairness of a twenty sided die (d20)?  Obviously I would be comparing the distribution of values against a uniform distribution.  I vaguely remember using a Chi-square test in college.  How can I apply this to see if a die is fair?

Comment: I have thought about a test for a d6 (six sided die). This included finding the number of rolls necessary to test. It is very basic but nevertheless takes long to compute. Have a look at http://localtrainbeplac.bplaced.net/die.php.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's an example with R code. The output is preceded by #'s.
A fair die:

```
rolls <- sample(1:20, 200, replace = T)
table(rolls)
#rolls
# 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
# 7  8 11  9 12 14  9 14 11  7 11 10 13  8  8  5 13  9 10 11 
 chisq.test(table(rolls), p = rep(0.05, 20))

#         Chi-squared test for given probabilities
#
# data:  table(rolls) 
# X-squared = 11.6, df = 19, p-value = 0.902
```

A biased die - numbers 1 to 10 each have a probability of 0.045; those 11-20 have a probability of 0.055 - 200 throws:

```
rolls <- sample(1:20, 200, replace = T, prob=cbind(rep(0.045,10), rep(0.055,10)))
table(rolls)
#rolls
# 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
# 8  9  7 12  9  7 14  5 10 12 11 13 14 16  6 10 10  7  9 11 
chisq.test(table(rolls), p = rep(0.05, 20))

#        Chi-squared test for given probabilities
#
# data:  table(rolls) 
# X-squared = 16.2, df = 19, p-value = 0.6439
```

We have insufficient evidence of bias (p = 0.64).

A biased die, 1000 throws:

```
rolls <- sample(1:20, 1000, replace = T, prob=cbind(rep(0.045,10), rep(0.055,10)))
table(rolls)
#rolls
# 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
# 42 47 34 42 47 45 48 43 42 45 52 50 57 57 60 68 49 67 42 63 
chisq.test(table(rolls), p = rep(0.05, 20))

#        Chi-squared test for given probabilities
#
# data:  table(rolls) 
# X-squared = 32.36, df = 19, p-value = 0.02846
```

Now p<0.05 and we are starting to see evidence of bias. You can use similar simulations to estimate the level of bias you can expect to detect and the number of throws needed to detect it with an given p-level.

Wow, 2 other answers even before I finished typing.

Comment: All the answers are similar, but slightly different. I don't think it really matters.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I accepted this because it included all the newbie stuff about p values and rejecting.

Answer (score 13):

Do you want to do it by hand, or in excel ?

If you want to do it in [R](http://www.r-project.org/), you can do it this way:

Step 1: roll your die (let's say) 100 times.

Step 2: count how many times you got each of your numbers

Step 3: put them in R like this (write the number of times each die roll you got, instead of the numbers I wrote):

```
x <- as.table(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,80,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20))
```

Step 4: simply run this command:

```
chisq.test(x)
```

If the P value is low (e.g: bellow 0.05) - your die is not balanced.

This command simulates a balanced die (P= ~.5):

```
chisq.test(table(sample(1:20, 100, T)))
```

And this simulates an unbalanced die:

```
chisq.test(table(c(rep(20,10),sample(1:20, 100, T))))
```

(It get's to be about P = ~.005)

Now the real question is how many die's should be rolled to what level of power of detection.  If someone wants to go into solving that, he is welcomed...

Update:  There is also a nice article on this topic [here](http://www.textfiles.com/rpg/fairdice.txt).

Comment: +1 for the reference: it's a lengthy treatise on practical die testing.  Halfway down the author suggests using a KS test and then goes into ways to identify specific forms of deviation from fairness.  He's also well aware that chi-square is an approximation for small numbers of rolls per face (e.g., for 100 rolls of a 20-sided die), that power varies, etc., etc.  In short, anything the OP might like to know is clearly laid out.

Answer (score 13):

If you are interested in just checking the number of times each number appears, then a Chi-squared test would be suitable. Suppose you roll a die N times. You would expect each value to come up N/20 times. All a chi-square test does is compare what you observed with what you get. If this difference is too large, then this would indicate a problem.

**Other tests**

If you were interested in other aspects of randonness, for example, if you dice gave the following output:

```
1, 2, 3, 4...., 20,1,2,..
```

Then although this output has the correct number of each individual value, it is clearly not random. In this case, take a look at this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30/testing-random-variate-generation-algorithms/). This probably only makes sense for electronic dice.

**Chi-squared test in R**

In R, this would be

```
##Roll 200 times
> rolls = sample(1:20, 200, replace=TRUE)
> chisq.test(table(rolls), p = rep(0.05, 20))
    Chi-squared test for given probabilities
data:  table(rolls) 
X-squared = 16.2, df = 19, p-value = 0.6439

## Too many 1's in the sample
> badrolls = cbind(rolls, rep(1, 10))   
> chisq.test(table(badrolls), p = rep(0.05, 20))

    Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  table(badrolls) 
X-squared = 1848.1, df = 19, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

Answer (score 13):

A chi-squared goodness of fit test aims to find all possible kinds of deviations from strict uniformity. This is reasonable with a d4 or a d6, but with a d20, you're probably more interested in checking that the probability that you roll under (or possibly exceed) each outcome is close to what it should be.

What I am getting at is that there are some kinds of deviations from fairness that will heavily impact whatever you're using a d20 for and other kinds of deviations that hardly matter at all, and the chi-squared test will divide power between more interesting and less interesting alternatives. The consequence is that to have enough power to pick up even fairly moderate deviations from fairness, you need a *huge* number of rolls - far more than you would ever want to sit and generate.

(Hint: come up with a few sets of non-uniform probabilities for your d20 that will most heavily impact the outcome that you're using the d20 for and use simulation and chi-squared tests to find out what power you have against them for various numbers of rolls, so you get some idea of the number of rolls you will need.)

There are a variety of ways of checking for "interesting" deviations (ones that will be more likely to substantively affect typical uses of a d20)

My recommendation is to do an ECDF test (Kolmogorov-Smirnov/Anderson-Darling-type test - but you'll probably want to adjust for the conservativeness that results from the distribution being discrete - at least by lifting the nominal alpha level, but even better by just simulating the distribution to see how the distribution of the test statistic goes for a d20). For example, this will have better power at finding a change in the probability of rolling at least some value (typically when a 20 sided die is used for something, it's rolling at least some target, or perhaps no more than some target). It would also have a better chance to find a change in the mean than a plain chi-squared test would -- though not as much as a test specifically designed to spot a change in mean. That would be a good thing to look for if you're adding results from multiple rolls (for example, in TTRPGs, picking up a change in mean would be important where a die is used for calculating damage totals).

These ECDF tests can still pick up any kind of deviation, but they put relatively more weight on the more important kinds of deviation for a 20-sided die.

An even more powerful approach is to specifically construct a test statistic that is more directly sensitive to the most important alternatives to you, but it involves a bit more work.

---

In [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/58442/805) I suggest a  graphical method for testing a die based on the size of the individual deviations. Like the chi-squared test this makes more sense for dice with few sides like d4 or d6.

Answer (score 9):

Nobody has suggested a Bayesian approach yet? I know the question has been answered already, but what the heck.  Below is for only a 3-sided die, but I'm guessing it's obvious how to fix it for $n=37$ sides.

First, in line with what @Glen_b said, a bayesian is not actually interested whether or not the die is *exactly* fair - it isn't. What (s)he cares about is whether it's close *enough*, whatever "enough" means in the context, say, within 5% of fair for each side.

If $p_1$, $p_2$, and $p_3$ represent the probabilites of rolling 1, 2, and 3, respectively, then we represent our prior knowledge about $p=(p_1,p_2,p_3)$ with a prior distribution, and to make the math easy we could choose a [Dirichlet distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution).  Note that $p_1+p_2+p_3=1$.  For a non-informative prior we might pick prior parameters, say, $\alpha_0=(1,1,1)$.

If $X=(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ represents the observed counts of 1,2,3 then of course $X$ has a [multinomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution) with parameters $p=(p_1,p_2,p_3)$, and the theory says that the posterior is also a Dirichlet distribution with parameters $\alpha=(x_1+1,x_2+1,x_3+1)$.  (Dirichlet is called a [conjugate prior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior), here.)

We observe data, find the posterior with Bayes' rule, then ALL inference is based on the posterior.  Want an estimate for $p$?  Find the mean of the posterior.  Want confidence intervals (no, rather [credible intervals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credible_interval))?  Calculate some areas under the posterior.  For complicated problems in the real world we usually simulate from the posterior and get simulated estimates for all of the above.

Anyway, here's how (with R):

First, get some data.  We roll the die 500 times.

```
set.seed(1)
y <- rmultinom(1, size = 500, prob = c(1,1,1))
```

(we're starting with a fair die; in practice these data would be observed.)

Next, we simulate 5000 observations of $p$ from the posterior and take a look at the results.

```
library(MCMCpack)
A <- MCmultinomdirichlet(y, alpha0 = c(1,1,1), mc = 5000)
plot(A)
summary(A)
```

Finally, let's estimate our posterior probability (after observing the data) that the die is within 0.05 of fair in each coordinate.

```
B <- as.matrix(A)
f <- function(x) all((x > 0.28)*(x < 0.38))
mean(apply(B, MARGIN = 1, FUN = f))
```

The result is about 0.9486 on my machine.  (Not a surprise, really.  We started with a fair die after all.)

Quick remark: it probably isn't reasonable for us to have used a non-informative prior in this example.  Since there's even a question presumably the die appears approximately balanced in the first place, so it may be better to pick a prior that is concentrated closer to 1/3 in all coordinates.  Above this would simply have made our estimated posterior probability of "close to fair" even higher.

Comment: Why we might prefer a bayesian approach than a frequentist in this example ??

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps one should not focus as much on one set of rolls.

Try rolling a 6 side die 10 times and repeat the process 8 times.

```
> xy <- rmultinom(10, n = N, prob = rep(1, K)/K)
> xy
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    3    1    0    0    1    1    2    1
[2,]    0    0    1    2    1    1    0    1
[3,]    1    3    6    0    1    3    2    4
[4,]    2    1    0    5    2    0    2    1
[5,]    3    2    0    2    1    3    3    0
[6,]    1    3    3    1    4    2    1    3
```

You can check that the sum for each repeat sums to 10.

```
> apply(xy, MARGIN = 2, FUN = sum)
[1] 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
```

For each repeat (column-wise) you can calculate goodness of fit using Chi^2 test.

```
unlist(unname(sapply(apply(xy, MARGIN = 2, FUN = chisq.test), "[", "p.value")))
[1] 0.493373524 0.493373524 0.003491841 0.064663031 0.493373524 0.493373524 0.669182902
[8] 0.235944538
```

The more throws you make, the less biased you will see. Let's do this for a large number.

```
K <- 20
N <- 10000

xy <- rmultinom(100, n = N, prob = rep(1, K)/K)
hist(unlist(unname(sapply(apply(xy, MARGIN = 2, FUN = chisq.test), "[", "p.value"))))
```

[image]