# Use chi-squared to check is numbers uniformly distributed

Tags: r, distributions, chi-squared-test, uniform-distribution

I want to check if the numbers produced by my random number generator are uniformly distributed. My code is below - is the statistical approach correct?

Disclaimers - this isn't homework, it's personal interest. And for the 'what research have you done' brigade, I have done a fair bit of rummaging on stats.stackexchange, and while there's plenty of similar questions I cannot find any that answer the above question specifically.

```
c(126L, 106L, 182L, 162L, 232L, 130L, 113L, 75L, 191L, 19L, 242L, 245L, 152L, 241L, 240L, 140L, 208L, 163L, 174L, 194L, 69L, 194L, 200L, 7L, 213L, 145L, 170L, 198L, 50L, 207L, 247L, 116L, 162L, 173L, 168L, 232L, 23L, 156L, 62L, 165L, 19L, 206L, 250L, 150L, 170L, 29L, 62L, 26L, 209L, 120L, 131L, 170L, 197L, 1L, 153L, 195L, 250L, 29L, 151L, 912L, 139L, 23L, 211L, 237L, 10L, 248L, 119L, 138L, 118L, 190L, 207L, 136L, 13L, 55L, 117L, 239L, 90L, 18L, 196L, 120L, 140L, 170L, 189L, 44L, 250L, 131L, 241L, 150L, 86L, 146L, 84L, 138L, 56L, 125L, 199L, 188L, 225L, 67L, 63L, 914L, 77L, 190L, 121L, 206L, 150L, 226L, 50L, 77L, 76L, 36L, 12L, 126L, 169L, 168L, 160L, 199L, 173L, 68L, 192L, 21L, 246L, 250L, 88L, 244L, 196L, 244L, 46L, 142L, 133L, 224L, 73L, 78L, 38L, 222L, 174L, 39L, 49L) -> numbers_from_random_app

table(numbers_from_random_app) -> distribution

stats::chisq.test(distribution)
```

Comment: This is indeed a good question that can be entertained by a well-researched answer. But merely checking whether the code is right or not seems to be on the line of off-topic (this is my opinion). Meanwhile, check these posts [Prove a random generated number is uniform distributed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24409639/prove-a-random-generated-number-is-uniform-distributed),  [Verifying that a random generator outputs a uniform distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/203974/verifying-that-a-random-generator-outputs-a-uniform-distribution).

Comment: The chi-squared test is not really designed for that table: you have $137$ values from $1$ up to $914$ so most numbers do not appear at all and the majority of the numbers which do appear appear $1$ time. Since your method ignores those which do not appear, it will not spot that there are no values from $251$ though to $911$, which suggests to me that the values were not selected from a uniform distribution on an interval

Comment: @User1865345 it isn't a question about programming. The code is correct in terms of running without errors. The question is about whether to or the statistics applied is correct - I have edited question.

Comment: I have voted to reopen @luciano.

Comment: "The code is correct in terms of running without errors": that's not a very reliable way to check the correctness of a piece of code.

Comment: You might look at the output from `table(numbers_from_random_app)` and see if that's the object you want to be testing.

Comment: Or maybe another way to see that this isn't doing what you want, start with a log-normal distribution of values, and follow the same process.  E.g.: `A = round(rlnorm(100, 0, 1), 2); hist(A); Table = table(A); Table; chisq.test(Table)`

Answer (score 2):

Consider the Kolmogorov-Smirnov (nonparametric) test that compares the cumulative distributions of two data sets.

- Null hypothesis: the two dataset are from the same continuous distribution
- If the p value is small, conclude that the two groups were sampled from populations with different distributions.

K-S test with similar distributions. Note that ecdf computes the cumulative distribution function (CDF)

```
data1 <- rnorm(100)
data2 <- rnorm(100)
ks.test(data1, data2)
plot ( ecdf ( data1 ) ); lines ( ecdf ( data2 ), col='red' )
```

K-S test with two different distributions

```
data1 <- rnorm(100)
data2 <- runif(100)
ks.test(data1, data2)
plot ( ecdf ( data1 ) ); lines ( ecdf ( data2 ), col='red' )
```

K-S test against a uniform distribution with parameters 0 and 1

```
data2 <- runif(100)
ks.test(data2,"punif",0,1)
```

In your case, the last example meets your needs as long as you know the parameters of your uniform distribution.