# How to do an equidistribution test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, frequency

Suppose I have a sample of $N$ numbers $a_1,\dots,a_N$ from $1,\dots,k$. How can I test whether they are equidistributed?

I'm not interested in a full randomness test as the order does not matter to me, so [Testing random variate generation algorithms](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30/testing-random-variate-generation-algorithms) is not relevant to me, neither are its dupes. For me, a sequence $1,2,3,\dots k,1,2,3,\dots,k,\dotsc$ is perfectly fine.

I would like to have a test just from the frequencies/counts, i.e., my input data really is the vector of number of occurrences $c_j=\#\{n\leq N:a_n=j\}$ for $j=1,\dots,k$. I was unable to google the way how to proceed.

Comment: Chi square test.

Comment: @user2974951 Thanks a lot, after some googling based on your help I found that I have to calculate $\chi^2=Nk\sum_{j=1}^k (c_j/N-1/k)^2$ and that I have $k-1$ degrees of freedom. But from this I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: See [these threads](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=chi+square*++test++score%3A2).

Comment: @whuber Thanks a lot! https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3194/how-can-i-test-the-fairness-of-a-d20 helped me really. Should I delete my question?

Comment: Good find!  Thank you for searching and for sharing the result of your search.